# How to deal with Polyhedron as region?

Tags: regions, geometry

I'm quite new to Mathematica and have big troubles with understanding regions correctly. Especially when using the function Polyhedron I'm completely stuck. According to the documentation, the function `Polyhedron[{f1,...,fn}]` "is a volume region, representing all the points inside the closed surface with polygon faces fi".

Now I construct a polyhedron as follows:

```
{p0, p1, p2, p3} = {{0, 0, 0}, {Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2, 0}, {Sqrt[3]/2, -(1/2), 0}, {0, 0, -3/2}};
polyhedron = Polyhedron[{{p1, p2, p3}, {p1, p2, p0}, {p1, p0, p3}, {p2, p3, p0}}];
```

I get `true` for `RegionQ@polyhedron` as expected, but why does `RegionMember[polyhedron,{0.1,0,-0.1}]` not even evaluate, althoug the specified point `{0.1,0,-0.1}` lies within the volume of the defined polyhedron.

Answer (score 5):

Here we use `BoundaryMeshRegion`

```
{p0, p1, p2,p3} = {{0, 0, 0}, {Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2, 0}, {Sqrt[3]/2, -(1/2), 0}, {0, 0, -3/2}};
polyhedron = 
  Polyhedron[{{p1, p2, p3}, {p1, p2, p0}, {p1, p0, p3}, {p2, p3, p0}}];
newpolyhedron = BoundaryMeshRegion[polyhedron];
RegionMember[newpolyhedron, {0.1, 0, -0.1}]
Graphics3D[{Red, Point[{0.1, 0, -0.1}], Cyan, Opacity[0.1], 
  newpolyhedron}, Boxed -> False]
```

> `True`

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution! However, it does not work for me. The line
`RegionMember[newpolyhedron, {0.1, 0, -0.1}]`
gives the error "A correctly specified region expected at position 1 of RegionMember[newpolyhedron, {0.1, 0, -0.1}]". What is the reason, that one first have to use BoundaryMeshRegion? I thought that Polyhedron already defines a volume region that should work together with RegionMember.

Comment: `BoundaryMesh` also work.

Comment: 12.1.1 work well. What is your version?

Comment: `Clear[polyhedron, newpolyhedron];
{p0, p1, p2, 
   p3} = {{0, 0, 0}, {Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2, 0}, {Sqrt[3]/2, -(1/2), 0}, {0, 
    0, -3/2}};
polyhedron = 
  Polyhedron[{{p1, p2, p3}, {p1, p2, p0}, {p1, p0, p3}, {p2, p3, p0}}];
newpolyhedron = BoundaryMesh[polyhedron];
RegionMember[newpolyhedron, {0.1, 0, -0.1}]` also gives error?

Comment: Yes, it gives the same error. I also tried restarting Mathematica, because I thought there was an issue with global variables or something. I have version 12.0.0.0